# Bash ${!variable}

Tags: bash

I am scratching my head on this one, can't find the bash reference talking about it.

In the code below

```
host_color=${uphost}_host_color
host_color=${!host_color}
```

What is the second line doing ? what does the !operator do in this case ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a short form for [indirect references](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html).

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=bas
$ echo ${!foo}
bas
```

The seemingly similar construction [${!foo*}](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#VARPREFIXM) expands to *the names of all variables whose name begin with foo*:

```
$ foo1=x
$ foo2=y
$ echo ${!foo*}
foo1 foo2
```

Comment: You got it, thank you. Now it makes complete sense, host_color=green, green is another variable with the color code.

Comment: +1 Seems to be what @Oliver's code is doing - basically setting `host_color` to the value of `${uphost}_host_color`.  No different from setting it to `${${uphost}_host_color}`, right?

Answer (score 1):

From the b[ash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.

Comment: is ${!prefix*} the same as ${!prefix} ?

Comment: I thought it would be the next entry in the manpage since @Oliver's post doesn't have the "*" or "@": `${!name[@]}` - "If **name** is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name.  If **name** is not an array, expands to 0 if **name** is set."

Comment: @Olivier: no, they are not the same. I've added the relevant bits from the bash manual.